# How to clone PDO object safely?

Tags: php, pdo, clone

I try to clone a PDO instance using `$pdo2 = clone $pdo`, but I get unexpected behaviour in some PHP versions:

- The error occurs when the cloned object is used in PHP ≥ 7.
- The PDO attributes are linked between the original and the cloned object in HHVM.
- Everything is OK in PHP 5.

Here is a code that reproduces the problem:

```
$pdo1 = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$pdo1->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "PDO 1 is OK\n";

$pdo2 = clone $pdo1;
$pdo2->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
echo "PDO 2 is OK\n";

echo $pdo1->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE) === $pdo2->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE)
    ? "❌ The attribute IS changed\n"
    : "✅ The attribute IS NOT changed\n";
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/vQg4S)

Is there any way to make an independent copy of a PDO object or at least copy only the DSN, username and password?

Why I need to clone a PDO instance: I need to keep a PDO instance isolated to reach goals:

- Modifying the cloned instance doesn't change the original instance.
- Modifying the original instance doesn't change the cloned instance.

Comment: Why can't you open a new PDO resource to your database? It's problematic to clone objects that act like resources.

Comment: @BillKarwin I can when I build a project. But I make a library which tries to be as solid as possible. PDO instance is a dependancy. A possibility to change the PDO instance decreases the library reliability.

Comment: If cloning PDO is impossible, I will just ask users to pass PDO constructor arguments instead of a PDO object and create a PDO instance inside the library.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to clone a PDO object safely. You should never have such an idea, as it makes no sense:

- if you want another instance to **share the same database connection**, then it cannot be isolated by definition. Another instance can set distinct SQL modes, start transactions, **close the connection** after all.
- if you want another instance to create another database connection, then it makes no sense to clone - just create a new one.

So if you want an isolated PDO instance, just create it.