# How to create multiple PDOs?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a question regarding PDOs in PHP. I declared everything like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

It works really well, but I still have a problem. I want to use this several times. Is it possible to clone it like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pdo0 = $pdo;
$pdo1 = $pdo;
$pdo2 = $pdo;
```

Does this work exactly the same like:

```
$pdo0 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes this would work. But, why? I don't see any need for this. You can make multiple calls with `$pdo` without assigning it to another variable.

Comment: Your first code will just be the same connection, your second code will have multiple connections.

Comment: It won't be a copy will it @NigelRen? Won't it be a reference? I.e. all the same connection object.

Comment: I was more meaning that it will be the same connection - so any commands will use that one connection.

Comment: I am interested in why you think you need multiple connections to the same database. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @NigelRen What benefit would having multiple connections to the same database using the same details?

Comment: use you can close the pdo object

Comment: Ah ok. It's the first time I work with PDOs to prevent sql-injections. I thought it would be necessary. But what would I have to do to clone the connection?

Comment: @A.Hart You would have to read my answer. If English is not your primary language then asking for a `clone` is probably a mistake.

Comment: There is NO NEED to clone a connection or to have more than one, unless you want to talk to more than one database from a single script

Comment: You can create a class, initiate PDO connection and use it

Comment: Actually @RakeshJakhar thats exactly what `new PDO()` does. Wrapping it in another class rarely actually achieves anything useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone PDO object safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923097/how-to-clone-pdo-object-safely)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make use of [object cloning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$pdo0 = clone $pdo;
$pdo1 = clone $pdo;
$pdo2 = clone $pdo;
```

I am honestly not sure how this would affect connection pooling and other intricacies/conveniences of PDO.

You should probably read [How to clone PDO object safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923097/2191572)

Comment: Yeah, I read this post but didn't understand that I can use the same connection for my use.

Comment: You never specified your use case. It is very dangerous to request a specific solution for a problem which you don't understand.

Comment: _Small Point_ Does not the answer you link to actually say your answer is a bad idea and should not be done? :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes but this cluster F of a XY Problem is only now being revealed. They asked "Can I?" and I answered "Of course you can but here is a discussion about whether or not you should."

Comment: I've been working with mysqli_connect so far. I really just want to do normal database operations. The only problem with mysqli_connect is that it is not so secure against sql-injections.

Comment: @A.Hart You requested to know how to perform a specific programming construct called "cloning" and provided absolutely zero context in your question. Once again, you are making a fatally invalid assumption because the `mysqli` library specifically has functions for securing against SQL injections.